# How to use notifyDataSetChanged from a different class ?

Tags: java, android

I have an Http call class I made to send some images. I want these requests to be done in the background so the user can continue doing whatever they want in the app.

When the call has finished executing, I want to remove the Item from the listview and update it.

Here is my code.

```
public HttpCall(ArrayList<Jobs> jobs, ArrayList<GridImages> images, ArrayList<GridImages> signatures, Context context,TwoColumnListAdapter customadapter) {
    this.jobs = jobs;
    this.images = images;
    this.signatures = signatures;
    this.context = context;

    listView = (SwipeMenuListView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adapter = customadapter;

    mydb = new Database_Helper(context);
}



public void SendALL(){

//Calls the http requests and then executes the update for the listview.


   listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


//          Intent intent = new Intent(context,AddJob.class);
//          context.startActivity(intent);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.remove(jobs.get(0));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

I could start a new Intent and then it will show that it updated the listview as the AddJob class makes a call to the database and updates the listview.

Comment: TBH it's hard to understand what you want

Comment: use AsyncTask and update list after postExecute.

Comment: @garywzh I just want to update a listview regardless whatever page the user is in.